# Can't populate Tkinter listbox from sqlite3 database

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I am making a simple Tkinter GUI in python 3.6.6 and i can't get data from a database to populate listbox.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeuQA.jpg

What is my problem? When i want to populate listbox with existing data from a sqlite3 database, i click on the "Refresh Data" button and encounter an error.
My code should select all rows in a first colon and put everything inside a listbox.
Important lines of code are included below:

```
db_conn = sqlite3.connect("dbs/entries.db")
cursor = db_conn.cursor()

def updateListbox(self):
    #Delete items in the list box
    self.listOfEntries.delete(0, "END")

    #Get users from the db
    try:

        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT Name FROM Entries")

        # Receive a list of lists that hold the result
        for row in result.fetchall():
            name = row[0]


        # Put the student in the list box
        self.listOfEntries.insert(name)

    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        print("The Table Doesn't Exist")

    except:
        print("1: Couldn't Retrieve Data From Database")
```

Every time i click on "Refresh Data" button i get "1: Couldn't Retrieve Data From Database" error.
The result of my code should just populate listbox.

Comment: Temporarily remove the `except` clause or add a `traceback.print_exc()` in it for further error details. Edit the question to show the traceback then if you need further help.

Comment: The `insert` method requires two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your "name" is just a variable and in every loop is updating his value...
so i think you need to move 'self.listOfEntries.insert(name)' inside of the loop.
as you have it only will show the last name in the list.

best,